# User Control in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a hyperlink enclosed in a label in my User Control. The problem is that the height is set according to the size of the text inside the label. How do I set the height in percentage so that the text doesn't touch the corners and is displayed in the middle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Anchor properties, so that it can remain in center.

Comment: CType(hypowner.FindControl("lblemp"),Label).Style.Add("height", "13px")
CType(hypowner.FindControl("lblemp"),Label).Style.Add("width", "114px")

Comment: How to set the width/ height in percentages??

Comment: I don't think you can set Height and Width in percentage.